# Speed of RNetLogo versus NetLogo Mathematica Link

Tags: netlogo

When driving NetLogo, I'd rather use Mathematica, not R. Yet I wonder if the RNetLogo package has advantages I'd be missing. Mostly speed, because the Mathematica Link has plenty of functionality.